# My implementation of the evaluation function and Alpha-beta pruning for Connect Four is not smart enough

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning

I am trying to implement correctly the Connect Four game AI yet not to avail my AI acts stupid:

- It does not block the opposite player pattern which can lead to failure of the AI,
- It does not take moves that might lead to AI's victory.

My project consists of the following two GitHub-repositories:

1. [**GameAI**](https://github.com/coderodde/GameAI),
2. [**ConnectFour**](https://github.com/coderodde/ConnectFour),

where **GameAI** contains:

#### SortingAlphaBetaPruningGameEngine

```
package net.coderodde.zerosum.ai.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.coderodde.zerosum.ai.EvaluatorFunction;
import net.coderodde.zerosum.ai.GameEngine;
import net.coderodde.zerosum.ai.State;

/**
 * This class implements the 
 * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax">Minimax</a> algorithm for 
 * zero-sum two-player games.
 * 
 * @param <S> the game state type.
 * @param <P> the player color type.
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (May 26, 2019)
 */
public final class SortingAlphaBetaPruningGameEngine
        <S extends State<S>, P extends Enum<P>> 
        extends GameEngine<S, P> {

    /**
     * Stores the terminal node or a node at the depth zero with the best value
     * so far, which belongs to the maximizing player moves.
     */
    private S bestTerminalMaximizingState;

    /**
     * Stores the value of {@code bestTerminalMaximizingState}.
     */
    private double bestTerminalMaximizingStateValue;

    /**
     * Stores the terminal node or a node at the depth zero with the best value
     * so far, which belongs to the minimizing player moves.
     */
    private S bestTerminalMinimizingState;

    /**
     * Stores the value of {@code bestTerminalMinimizingState}.
     */
    private double bestTerminalMinimizingStateValue;

    /**
     * Indicates whether we are computing a next ply for the minimizing player 
     * or not. If not, we are computing a next ply for the maximizing player.
     */
    private boolean makingPlyForMinimizingPlayer;

    /**
     * Maps each visited state to its parent state.
     */
    private final Map<S, S> parents = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Constructs this minimax game engine.
     * @param evaluatorFunction the evaluator function.
     * @param depth the search depth.
     */
    public SortingAlphaBetaPruningGameEngine(
            EvaluatorFunction<S> evaluatorFunction,
            int depth) {
        super(evaluatorFunction, depth, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public S makePly(S state, 
                     P minimizingPlayer,
                     P maximizingPlayer,
                     P initialPlayer) {
        // Reset the best known values:
        bestTerminalMaximizingStateValue = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        bestTerminalMinimizingStateValue = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        makingPlyForMinimizingPlayer = initialPlayer != minimizingPlayer;

        // Do the game tree search:
        makePlyImpl(state,
                    depth,
                    Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, // intial alpha
                    Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, // intial beta
                    minimizingPlayer,
                    maximizingPlayer,
                    initialPlayer);

        // Find the next game state starting from 'state':
        S returnState =
                inferBestState(
                        initialPlayer == minimizingPlayer ? 
                                bestTerminalMinimizingState : 
                                bestTerminalMaximizingState);

        // Release the resources:
        parents.clear();
        bestTerminalMaximizingState = null;
        bestTerminalMinimizingState = null;
        // We are done with a single move:
        return returnState;
    }

    private S inferBestState(S bestTerminalState) {
        List<S> statePath = new ArrayList<>();
        S state = bestTerminalState;

        while (state != null) {
            statePath.add(state);
            state = parents.get(state);
        }

        if (statePath.size() == 1) {
            // The root node is terminal. Return null:
            return null;
        }

        // Return the second upmost state:
        Collections.<S>reverse(statePath);
        return statePath.get(1);
    }

    /**
     * Performs a single step down the game tree branch.
     * 
     * @param state the starting state.
     * @param depth the maximum depth of the game tree.
     * @param minimizingPlayer the minimizing player.
     * @param maximizingPlayer the maximizing player.
     * @param currentPlayer the current player.
     * @return the value of the best ply.
     */
    private double makePlyImpl(S state,
                               int depth,
                               double alpha,
                               double beta,
                               P minimizingPlayer,
                               P maximizingPlayer,
                               P currentPlayer) {
        if (depth == 0 || state.isTerminal()) {
            double value = evaluatorFunction.evaluate(state);

            if (!makingPlyForMinimizingPlayer) {
                if (bestTerminalMinimizingStateValue > value) {
                    bestTerminalMinimizingStateValue = value;
                    bestTerminalMinimizingState = state;
                }
            } else {
                if (bestTerminalMaximizingStateValue < value) {
                    bestTerminalMaximizingStateValue = value;
                    bestTerminalMaximizingState = state;
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

        if (currentPlayer == maximizingPlayer) {
            double value = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            List<S> children = state.children();
            children.sort((S a, S b) -> {
                double valueA = super.evaluatorFunction.evaluate(a);
                double valueB = super.evaluatorFunction.evaluate(b);
                return Double.compare(valueB, valueA);
            });

            for (S child : children) {
                value = Math.max(
                        value, 
                        makePlyImpl(child, 
                                    depth - 1, 
                                    alpha,
                                    beta,
                                    minimizingPlayer, 
                                    maximizingPlayer, 
                                    minimizingPlayer));

                parents.put(child, state);
                alpha = Math.max(alpha, value);

                if (alpha >= beta) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return value;
        } else {
            // Here, 'initialPlayer == minimizingPlayer'.
            double value = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            List<S> children = state.children();
            children.sort((S a, S b) -> {
                double valueA = super.evaluatorFunction.evaluate(a);
                double valueB = super.evaluatorFunction.evaluate(b);
                return Double.compare(valueA, valueB);
            });

            for (S child : children) {
                value = Math.min(
                        value,
                        makePlyImpl(child, 
                                    depth - 1,
                                    alpha,
                                    beta,
                                    minimizingPlayer, 
                                    maximizingPlayer, 
                                    maximizingPlayer));

                parents.put(child, state);
                beta = Math.min(beta, value);

                if (alpha >= beta) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

and I have two evaluation functions from the web/my head. The first one (see below), finds all the patterns of length 2, 3 and 4 and multiplies their occurrence counts by the constants that will favour the longer of them. Didn't seem to work. Another one maintains a matrix of integers; each integer denotes the number of patterns that may occupy the slot of that integers. Didn't work either.

#### BruteForceConnectFourStateEvaluatorFunction

```
package net.coderodde.games.connect.four.impl;

import net.coderodde.games.connect.four.ConnectFourState;
import net.coderodde.games.connect.four.PlayerColor;
import net.coderodde.zerosum.ai.EvaluatorFunction;

/**
 * This class implements the default Connect Four state evaluator. The white 
 * player wants to maximize, the red player wants to minimize.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (May 24, 2019)
 */
public final class BruteForceConnectFourStateEvaluatorFunction
        implements EvaluatorFunction<ConnectFourState> {

    private static final double POSITIVE_WIN_VALUE = 1e9;
    private static final double NEGATIVE_WIN_VALUE = -1e9;
    private static final double POSITIVE_CLOSE_TO_WIN_VALUE = 1e6;
    private static final double NEGATIVE_CLOSE_TO_WIN_VALUE = -1e6;
    private static final double BASE_VALUE = 1e1;

    /**
     * The weight matrix. Maps each position to its weight. We need this in 
     * order to 
     */
    private final double[][] weightMatrix;

    /**
     * The winning length.
     */
    private final int winningLength;

    /**
     * Constructs the default heuristic function for Connect Four game states.
     * 
     * @param width the game board width.
     * @param height the game board height.
     * @param maxWeight the maximum weight in the weight matrix.
     * @param winningPatternLength the winning pattern length.
     */
    public BruteForceConnectFourStateEvaluatorFunction(final int width,
                                             final int height,
                                             final double maxWeight,
                                             final int winningPatternLength) {
        this.weightMatrix = getWeightMatrix(width, height, maxWeight);
        this.winningLength = winningPatternLength;
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates the given input {@code state} and returns the estimate.
     * @param state the state to estimate.
     * @return the estimate.
     */
    @Override
    public double evaluate(ConnectFourState state) {
        PlayerColor winnerPlayerColor = state.checkVictory();

        if (winnerPlayerColor == PlayerColor.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER) {
            return POSITIVE_WIN_VALUE - state.getDepth();
        }

        if (winnerPlayerColor == PlayerColor.MINIMIZING_PLAYER) {
            return NEGATIVE_WIN_VALUE + state.getDepth();
        }

        // 'minimizingPatternCounts[i]' gives the number of patterns of 
        // length 'i':
        int[] minimizingPatternCounts = new int[state.getWinningLength() + 1];
        int[] maximizingPatternCounts = new int[minimizingPatternCounts.length];

        // Do not consider patterns of length one!
        for (int targetLength = 2; 
                targetLength <= winningLength; 
                targetLength++) {
            int count = findMinimizingPatternCount(state, targetLength);

            if (count == 0) {
                // Once here, it is not possible to find patterns of larger 
                // length than targetLength:
                break;
            }

            minimizingPatternCounts[targetLength] = count;
        }

        for (int targetLength = 2;
                targetLength <= state.getWinningLength();
                targetLength++) {
            int count = findMaximizingPatternCount(state, targetLength);

            if (count == 0) {
                // Once here, it is not possible to find patterns of larger
                // length than targetLength:
                break;
            }

            maximizingPatternCounts[targetLength] = count;
        }

        double score = computeBaseScore(minimizingPatternCounts, 
                                        maximizingPatternCounts);
        score += computeAlmostFullPatternScores(state, winningLength);
        return score + getWeights(weightMatrix, state);
    }

    private static final double 
        computeAlmostFullPatternScores(ConnectFourState state,
                                       int winningLength) {
        final int targetLength = winningLength - 2;
        double score = 0.0;

        for (int y = state.getHeight() - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            loop:
            for (int x = 0; x < state.getWidth() - targetLength; x++) {
                if (state.readCell(x, y) == null) {
                    // Try to find 'targetLength' marks:
                    PlayerColor targetPlayerColor = state.readCell(x + 1, y);

                    if (targetPlayerColor == null) {
                        continue loop;
                    }

                    int currentLength = 1;

                    for (int xx = x + 1; xx < state.getWidth() - 1; xx++) {
                        if (state.readCell(xx, y) == targetPlayerColor) {
                            currentLength++;

                            if (currentLength == targetLength) {
                                if (state.getPlayerColor() ==
                                        PlayerColor.MINIMIZING_PLAYER) {
                                    score += NEGATIVE_CLOSE_TO_WIN_VALUE;
                                } else {
                                    score += POSITIVE_CLOSE_TO_WIN_VALUE;
                                }

                                continue loop;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return score;
        }

        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the number of red patterns of length {@code targetLength}.
     * @param state the target state.
     * @param targetLength the length of the pattern to find.
     * @return the number of red patterns of length {@code targetLength}.
     */
    private static final int findMinimizingPatternCount(ConnectFourState state,
                                                        int targetLength) {
        return findPatternCount(state, 
                                targetLength, 
                                PlayerColor.MINIMIZING_PLAYER);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the number of white patterns of length {@code targetLength}. 
     * @param state the target state.
     * @param targetLength the length of the pattern to find.
     * @return the number of white patterns of length {@code targetLength}.
     */
    private static final int findMaximizingPatternCount(ConnectFourState state,
                                                   int targetLength) {
        return findPatternCount(state,
                                targetLength, 
                                PlayerColor.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER);
    }

    /**
     * Implements the target pattern counting function for both the player 
     * colors.
     * @param state the state to search.
     * @param targetLength the length of the patterns to count.
     * @param playerColor the target player color.
     * @return the number of patterns of length {@code targetLength} and color
     * {@code playerColor}.
     */
    private static final int findPatternCount(ConnectFourState state,
                                              int targetLength,
                                              PlayerColor playerColor) {
        int count = 0;

        count += findHorizontalPatternCount(state, 
                                            targetLength, 
                                            playerColor);

        count += findVerticalPatternCount(state, 
                                          targetLength, 
                                          playerColor);

        count += findAscendingDiagonalPatternCount(state, 
                                                   targetLength,
                                                   playerColor);

        count += findDescendingDiagonalPatternCount(state, 
                                                    targetLength,
                                                    playerColor);
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Scans the input state for diagonal <b>descending</b> patterns and 
     * returns the number of such patterns.
     * @param state the target state.
     * @param patternLength the target pattern length.
     * @param playerColor the target player color.
     * @return the number of patterns.
     */
    private static final int 
        findDescendingDiagonalPatternCount(ConnectFourState state,
                                           int patternLength,
                                           PlayerColor playerColor) {
        int patternCount = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < state.getWinningLength() - 1; y++) {
            inner:
            for (int x = 0;
                    x <= state.getWidth() - state.getWinningLength(); 
                    x++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < patternLength; i++) {
                    if (state.readCell(x + i, y + i) != playerColor) {
                        continue inner;
                    }
                }

                patternCount++;
            }
        }

        return patternCount;
    }

    /**
     * Scans the input state for diagonal <b>ascending</b> patterns and returns
     * the number of such patterns.
     * @param state the target state.
     * @param patternLength the target pattern length.
     * @param playerColor the target player color.
     * @return the number of patterns.
     */
    private static final int 
        findAscendingDiagonalPatternCount(ConnectFourState state,
                                          int patternLength,
                                          PlayerColor playerColor) {
        int patternCount = 0;

        for (int y = state.getHeight() - 1;
                y > state.getHeight() - state.getWinningLength();
                y--) {

            inner:
            for (int x = 0; 
                    x <= state.getWidth() - state.getWinningLength();
                    x++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < patternLength; i++) {
                    if (state.readCell(x + i, y - i) != playerColor) {
                        continue inner;
                    }
                }

                patternCount++;
            }
        }

        return patternCount;
    } 

    /**
     * Scans the input state for diagonal <b>horizontal</b> patterns and returns
     * the number of such patterns.
     * @param state the target state.
     * @param patternLength the target pattern length.
     * @param playerColor the target player color.
     * @return the number of patterns.
     */
    private static final int findHorizontalPatternCount(
            ConnectFourState state,
            int patternLength,
            PlayerColor playerColor) {
        int patternCount = 0;

        for (int y = state.getHeight() - 1; y >= 0; y--) {

            inner:
            for (int x = 0; x <= state.getWidth() - patternLength; x++) {
                if (state.readCell(x, y) == null) {
                    continue inner;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < patternLength; i++) {
                    if (state.readCell(x + i, y) != playerColor) {
                        continue inner;
                    }
                }

                patternCount++;
            }
        }

        return patternCount;
    }

    /**
     * Scans the input state for diagonal <b>vertical</b> patterns and returns
     * the number of such patterns.
     * @param state the target state.
     * @param patternLength the target pattern length.
     * @param playerColor the target player color.
     * @return the number of patterns.
     */
    private static final int findVerticalPatternCount(ConnectFourState state,
                                                      int patternLength,
                                                      PlayerColor playerColor) {
        int patternCount = 0;

        outer:
        for (int x = 0; x < state.getWidth(); x++) {
            inner:
            for (int y = state.getHeight() - 1;
                    y > state.getHeight() - state.getWinningLength(); 
                    y--) {
                if (state.readCell(x, y) == null) {
                    continue outer;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < patternLength; i++) {
                    if (state.readCell(x, y - i) != playerColor) {
                        continue inner;
                    }
                }

                patternCount++;
            }
        }

        return patternCount;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the state weight. We use this in order to discourage the positions
     * that are close to borders/far away from the center of the game board.
     * @param weightMatrix the weighting matrix.
     * @param state the state to weight.
     * @return the state weight.
     */
    private static final double getWeights(final double[][] weightMatrix,
                                           final ConnectFourState state) {
        double score = 0.0;

        outer:
        for (int x = 0; x < state.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = state.getHeight() - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
                PlayerColor playerColor = state.readCell(x, y);

                if (playerColor == null) {
                    continue outer;
                }

                if (playerColor == PlayerColor.MINIMIZING_PLAYER) {
                    score -= weightMatrix[y][x];
                } else {
                    score += weightMatrix[y][x];
                }
            }
        }

        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the base scorer that relies on number of patterns. For example,
     * {@code redPatternCounts[i]} will denote the number of patterns of length 
     * [@code i}.
     * @param minimizingPatternCounts the pattern count map for red patterns.
     * @param maximizingPatternCounts the pattern count map for white patterns.
     * @return the base estimate.
     */
    private static final double computeBaseScore(
            int[] minimizingPatternCounts,
            int[] maximizingPatternCounts) {
        final int winningLength = minimizingPatternCounts.length - 1;

        double value = 0.0;

        if (minimizingPatternCounts[winningLength] != 0) {
            value = NEGATIVE_WIN_VALUE;
        }

        if (maximizingPatternCounts[winningLength] != 0) {
            value = POSITIVE_WIN_VALUE;
        }

        for (int length = 2; length < minimizingPatternCounts.length; length++) {
            int minimizingCount = minimizingPatternCounts[length];
            value -= minimizingCount * Math.pow(BASE_VALUE, length);

            int maximizingCount = maximizingPatternCounts[length];
            value += maximizingCount * Math.pow(BASE_VALUE, length);
        }

        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the weight matrix. The closer the entry in the board is to the
     * center of the board, the closer the weight of that position will be to
     * {@code maxWeight}.
     * 
     * @param width the width of the matrix.
     * @param height the height of the matrix.
     * @param maxWeight the maximum weight. The minimum weight will be always
     * 1.0.
     * @return the weight matrix. 
     */
    private static final double[][] getWeightMatrix(final int width,
                                                    final int height,
                                                    final double maxWeight) {
        final double[][] weightMatrix = new double[height][width];

        for (int y = 0; y < weightMatrix.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < weightMatrix[0].length; x++) {
                int left = x;
                int right = weightMatrix[0].length - x - 1;
                int top = y;
                int bottom = weightMatrix.length - y - 1;
                int horizontalDifference = Math.abs(left - right);
                int verticalDifference = Math.abs(top - bottom);
                weightMatrix[y][x] =
                        1.0 + (maxWeight - 1.0) / 
                              (horizontalDifference + verticalDifference);
            }
        }

        return weightMatrix;
    }
}
```

#### WeightMatrixConnectFourStateEvaluatorFunction

```
package net.coderodde.games.connect.four.impl;

import net.coderodde.games.connect.four.ConnectFourState;
import net.coderodde.games.connect.four.PlayerColor;
import net.coderodde.zerosum.ai.EvaluatorFunction;

/**
 * This evaluation function relies on a weight matrix that reflects how many
 * patterns visit each matrix position.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 19, 2019)
 */
public class WeightMatrixConnectFourStateEvaluatorFunction implements EvaluatorFunction<ConnectFourState> {

    private final double[][] matrix;

    public WeightMatrixConnectFourStateEvaluatorFunction() {
        this.matrix =  new double[][] {{3, 4,  5,  7,  5, 4, 3}, 
                                       {4, 6,  8, 10,  8, 6, 4},
                                       {5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5}, 
                                       {5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5},
                                       {4, 6,  8, 10,  8, 6, 4},
                                       {3, 4,  5,  7,  5, 4, 3}};
    }

    @Override
    public double evaluate(ConnectFourState state) {
        PlayerColor winner = state.checkVictory();

        if (winner == PlayerColor.MINIMIZING_PLAYER) {
            return -1e6;
        }

        if (winner == PlayerColor.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER) {
            return 1e6;
        }

        double sum = 0.0;

        for (int y = 0; y < state.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < state.getWidth(); x++) {
                if (state.readCell(x, y) == PlayerColor.MAXIMIZING_PLAYER) {
                    sum += matrix[y][x];
                } else if (state.readCell(x, y) ==
                        PlayerColor.MINIMIZING_PLAYER) {
                    sum -= matrix[y][x];
                }
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

I am completely clueless why both the evaluator functions fail to provide smart gaming. Any advice?

Comment: Have you tested if your alpha-beta engine works with another type of game? Then probably your evaluation functions are the problem. Otherwise there could also be a bug in the engine itself. I just like to know where to look first.

Comment: If there is more than 2 bugs, and you fixed about 5, don't even think about fixing the next one. All you are doing is making it more complicated. Copy the file(s) to another directory. Then take bits out of the project until the problem disappears. Then you add all but the last bit you took off back on. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Advice: start writing regression tests. Your GitHub projects have almost zero tests, even small bugs will take long time to debug.

Comment: I shall take a look at this in a few hours.

Answer (score -4):

Winning and losing moves in a case like this are not heuristic functions, they are binary yes/no discrete answers. You shouldn't be treating them heuristically for a simple game like connect 4. You test each move "will this win?" (if so do it). If no, test each move "does this prevent the other player from winning on their next move?" (again, if so, do it). After that you apply heuristics to find the best move of those available.

I suspect you're running into problems like "a winning move in a corner (3 value) will never beat a losing move in the middle (13 value)".

Comment: Winning and losing in chess is also binary, yet evaluation functions are used to help determine which states are worth exploring or not.